# Can I set a specific group|umask to be the default one for all actions within a certain path?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown, umask, htdocs

I would like to override the default `umask` and `owner:group` settings within certain directories only, without requiring root privileges, as that kind of defeats the purpose.

For example, when I `touch` a file in `/var/www/` it becomes `0755` and owned by `redsandro:redsandro`.

I would like this to default to `0770` and `redsandro:www-data` for everything within `/var/www/`.

Maybe there's a better solution for this specific scenario. This seemed to be the only way to have both my non-root user and the webserver in full control over `/var/www/`. As the only user of this machine, I like the `htdocs` to be 'mine' without being root. Apache becomes fed up though when you take too much territory inside htdocs.

[Here is a related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44534/how-to-set-umask-for-a-specific-folder) for the `umask` part where the answer is *"no"*. But I am sure others have sought the same functionality, and I can imagine `pwd` based `umask` is available somehow just like `git` uses `.git` to store `pwd` independent settings that go up the directory-tree. Or down, I'm not sure if you call subdirectories up or down the tree. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Partial answer:

Add the `setgid` bit on the parent directory:

```
sudo chown redsandro:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod 2770 /var/www
```

alternately:

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rwxs /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you desire both `user` and `group` set this should work.

```
sudo chown -R redsandro:www-data /var/www
```

To change ownership.

Then do:

```
sudo u=rwx, g=rwxs /var/www
```

To keep that ownership change above permanent.

Comment: Setuid on directories has no effect.

Comment: @muru please I would need an explanation on this as I have done this with a folder on mu `Ubuntu Xenial` here is the result of `stat -c %A www`, drwsrwsr-x. Still any info will appraciated

Comment: you'll see the setuid bit in the output, you won't see any *effect* of it.